# slick way to query sqlite db with millions of queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 db with about 400 key-value pairs. I would like to know what would be a preferred way to query this db given I have 2-3 million of keys for which I want to find out the values.

I ask because I am not sure what would be a good threshold in terms of number of queries I should make. How many keys should I include in my search query?

```
select * from db_name where col_name in ( <optimum number of keys that I should search>)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not put the keys into a table and just `JOIN` it, since, you know, it's SQL?

Comment: You have 400 key-value pairs in your database, but you want to select 2-3 million of them? It is not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I store the 400 million keys/values for future look ups..so when I get a new set of known keys which are 2-3 million at a time I need to find the values for them if they are present in the db ? I hope it is clear now

Comment: Sounds like something you should **try**.

Answer (score 1):

What @JNK noted.

A `select` query with 400 string literals in an `in` clause would likely run...poorly.

Create a table, something like:

```
create table key_lookup
(
  name varchar(32) not null primary key clustered ,
)
```

Make sure it's clustered (and unique) on the lookup value. Then run your select against that table:

```
select t.*
from some_table t
join key_lookup k on k.name = t.some_column
```

I don't know about sqlite3, but if `some_table` has a usable index on the key column you should get pretty good performance. Worst case, you should get a table scan on the `some_table` and clustered index seeks against the `key_lookup` table, which shouldn't suck too badly.